# Eclipse with MoreUnit - Running test with Ctrl+R gives error: "Cannot find 'junit.framework.TestCase' on project build path

Tags: eclipse, testng, moreunit

I have defined a class like this:

```
@Service
public class StoreService { ... }
```

Now, with MoreUnit installed i press Ctrl+J and a dialog box pops up and I create the corresponding test class:

```
@Test
public class StoreServiceTest { ... }
```

This is all fine, and I am now able to move back and forth between my implementation class and test class using Ctrl+J.

The problem comes when I try to run the test using Ctrl+R. In some Eclipse projects this works fine, but in other projects I get the following message:

> Cannot find 'junit.framework.TestCase' on the project build path.
>   JUnit 3 tests can only be run if JUnit is on the build path.

Now this is a bit annoying since I am not using JUnit at all, but TestNG instead.

I have searched through the Eclipse project settings a couple of times with no luck. But I am quite sure the solution is in there somewhere. I was kinda hoping that someone a bit more experienced in the ways of "Eclipse project configuration" could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this still needed, but here. You can set this in the preferences, [like the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zodMH.png)

Comment: Already tried this, but Eclipse is still trying to run the tests as JUnit tests..

Comment: On some projects, however, this is not an issue.. Seems like Eclipse gets stuck with some old config in some of the projects.